# How to measure the width of a div with overflow content

Tags: javascript, yui

I have a div with a width of 200px. There is text inside that is set **not** to wrap. So there is overflow. I need to get the width of the content of the div including the overflow.

I am using this for a YUI autocomplete dropdown menu. I want the dropdown to grow horizontally if the width of a result is greater than the width of the div.

How can I get the width of the content (not the css width, so offsetWidth doesn't work) including the overflow?

Comment: What kind of overflow? overflow:hidden? overflow:scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scrollWidth / scrollHeight properties.